# Find side lengths when 1 side, and right angle, are given.

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

The basic problem I’m having is only 1 side is given, and I’m assuming 1 of the angles are a right angle. This chapter deals with right triangle trigonometry.

If the offset portion of the conduit (segment BC) is the hypotenuse, and one leg of the triangle is 4.75m, how do you find the sides and angles of a right triangle when you’re given only one side and the right angle? I know how to use trigonometric functions to solve angles and sides when two angles are given, but not one.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Because the entire conduit is $30$ m long, you also can calculate the length of the hypoteneuse, so you actually know (or can determine) two sides of your right triangle.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Since the total length is $\space 30\space m,\space 
BC=\space 30-8-12=10\space m.\quad$

Since the base is
$\space  4.75\space m,\space $
$\space  x=\sqrt{10^2-4.75^2}\approx 8.8\space m.\quad $

Since the altitude is $\space 8.8\space m, \space $
$\space AD=\sqrt{24.75^2+8.8^2}=26.27\space m .\quad  $

Since $\space AD=26.27,\space 30-26.27=3.73\space m\space$ could be saved.

Comment: Please do not answer questions that do not meet the [quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards)

Answer (score 1):

In such questions you should be trying to find out triangles, for example for the second part of the question we find this triangle :

[image]

for the last part you should see this triangle:

[image]

then solve the question by the formulas you have, the first step is to discover the triangle the rest is simple.

Comment: Please do not answer questions that do not meet the [quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards).

Comment: Thank you for your help! And, why does my question not meet “quality standards”?